# Как конвертировать png или jpg в webp в webpack`e

Tags: gulp, webpack, png, jpeg, webp

Для Gulp есть плагин gulp-webp, который конвертирует изображения в формат .webp

Есть ли аналог для webpack`a и как им пользоваться?

Comment: Привет. Смотри webp-loader.

Comment: @Aleksandr, а чего не в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да вроде не за что "награждать"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл говорит про [`imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin).
Пользоваться как обычно - установил, подключил, настроил и пользуешься.

```
const ImageminWebpWebpackPlugin= require("imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new ImageminWebpWebpackPlugin(/*options*/)]
};
```